# My appended elements don't catch 'on' event

Tags: javascript, jquery

fellas. I have this code that appends a row with some elements, among them an input file:

```
$('#uploadDocumentoEnviarAseguradora').on('click', function() {
    var num_ficheros = $('.lista-ficheros').length + 1;

    var linea = '<div class="form-group"><div class="row form-horizontal lista-ficheros"><div class="col-xs-9"></div><input type="file" id="docEnviarAseguradora' + num_ficheros + '" class="documentoEnviarAseguradora"/><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="uploadDocumento"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div></div>';
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().append(linea);
    $("#docEnviarAseguradora" + num_ficheros).click();
});
```

And I have that one that handles when that new input file gets clicked.

```
$('documentoEnviarAseguradora').on('change',function() {
    alert("pos ok");
});
```

But I get no response when I load the file on my input file. Can you see what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Bad selector (missing the dot for a selection by class) and lack of [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) (needed because the element is added after the call to `on`).

Use

```
$(document.body).on('change','.documentoEnviarAseguradora',function() {
    alert("pos ok");
});
```

If possible, use a better element than `$(document.body)` to limit event handling.

Comment: Reference to [jQuery `on()` delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: Correct answer, but worth emphasizing the word `delegation` and sending the OP back to the  [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  for more info.

Comment: that missing dot was a fail when copypasting ;) thank you very much!